# I'm having trouble following this spherical coordinates integration.

Tags: integration, absolute-value, spherical-coordinates

[Photo of the integration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5sFw.png)

It's basically a triple integral in spherical coordinates. I understand how they did the integration wrt $\phi$ and $\theta$, but I don't understand the "trick" for doing it wrt $r$ since they get an absolute value thing in there.

Is there some u-substitution that I'm supposed to be doing? The $\frac{1}{rz}$ is especially making it harder.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: It's from a solution manual, it's printed and very legible.

Comment: I didn't say otherwise. But pictures eventually disappear from the Internet. Of course, in those cases such as the diagram contained in your solution, posting pictures is unavoidable. But this doesn't apply to text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
I(z,r)=\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{z^2+r^2-2rz\cos\theta}} d\theta
$$
is the one giving trouble, if I understand correctly. In these cases, if it is one of the first few times you are facing these integrals, it can be useful to substitute $\cos\theta = u$, so that $-\sin\theta\, d\theta = du$ and we are able to perform the integral with respect to $u$ directly
$$
I(z,r) = \int_{-1}^{+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+r^2-2rzu}}du = -\frac{1}{rz}\sqrt{z^2+r^2-2rzu}\Big|_{-1}^{+1}=\frac{1}{rz}(\sqrt{z^2+2rz + r^2}-\sqrt{z^2-2rz+r^2})
=\frac{1}{rz}(\sqrt{(z+r)^2}-\sqrt{(z-r)^2})
$$
and, since $\sqrt{\alpha^2}=|\alpha|$ for any real number $\alpha$, we have
$$
I(z,r)=\frac{1}{rz}(|z+r|-|z-r|)\,.
$$
I see from the picture that your textbook assumes $z\ge0$, while $r$ is always nonnegative since it is the radial coordinate; then the first absolute value is actually not necessary. The second one must be discussed as you see there.